# Using NotePad++ or Command Line to replace text?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command, notepad++

I am trying to use Notepad++ to replace random text across all of the file I have opened.  I believe that I'm supposed to be using regular expression but just can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I need to replace:

```
$l = 'this is all random text'
```

Where it says `this is all random text` it will be different text in each file.

I want to replace it with this:

```
$l = 'my new text'
```

That way all of my files have the exact same text in that spot.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I'm also open to doing this in command line if that's easier...

Comment: what's the pattern in that so called random text. I believe there can't be a regex for any random text, there has to be well defined deterministic pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to Notepad++
Hit STR+F.

You will see the following dialogue:

[image]

Go to the Replace tab (as marked in the picture. And check the check box 'Regular expression. Now you can type your regular expression in the find dialogue.
Add the text you would like to replace.

If you are unsure about how to write a regex in Notepad++, you should have a look at this:

http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions

Now you can hit the "Replace in All Documents" Button and you are done.